# Iphone custom Navigation Bar Button with SystemButtonImage

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem

I'm working with custom navigationBarButtons so I can give them a different tint-color thant the navigation Bar.

But I can't see a way to get them to show a systemButton (Like the symbol for reloading).

I guess these are private. Does anyone of you have matching symbols/images I can use?

Answer (score 2):

If you're subclassing UIBarButtonItem, then you should still be able to init it with the `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` method. You can pass in a systemItem for refresh (reload) or add, etc..

If you need custom init behaviour, consider overriding this method in your subclass, just remember to call the super implementation.

Comment: I still don't see how to get this done, sorry :/
A UIBarButtonItem doesn't have a view but is being interpreted by the NavigationBar.
And adding a customView results in the SystemItemType being ignored.

Comment: Using a custom view and using a system type are mutually exclusive. You can't have both in the same UIBarButtonItem. I only assumed you were subclassing UIBarButtonItem since you said "custom navigation bar button". Is this true? Or are you using a vanilla UIBarButtonItem init'd with a custom view?

Comment: actually thats what I got so far
http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/4892/navigationaz.png
and the right button is what bothers me ;)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, are you subclassing UIBarButtonItem or creating a standard UIBarBarButtonItem using the initWithWithCustomView: method?

Comment: How did you get the green back button? and why won't the same method work for the right side button?

Comment: The back-Button is created using a custom view, which would also be possible for the right side button, but only if I were in posession of the original image-File from Apple... which I am now :D